# Display Matrix block field base on location of query

Tags: matrix

`supportContent` is a Matrix field
`contentBlock` is a Matrix block
`heading` and `body` are fields within `contentBlock`

I am trying to display `block.heading` only if my `query` is in the `block.body`

```
{% for block in entry.supportContent.type('contentBlock') if query in block.body  %}
    <h3>{{ block.heading }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```

This code is not working. Any help?

Comment: What's `query`? A string?

Comment: Yes @BradBell `{% set query = craft.request.getParam('q') %}`

Comment: What's `block.body`? A text field?

Comment: `block.body` is rich text, `block.heading` is plain text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would work as-is if `block.body` was a [Plain Text field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plain-text-fields).

But since it's a [Rich Text field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/rich-text-fields), it technically returns a [RichTextData](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/fieldtypes/RichTextData) object and Twig's `in` operator doesn't know what to do with objects.

This will grab the string data from the Rich Text field so `in` operates as you'd expect.

```
{% for block in entry.supportContent.type('contentBlock') if query in block.body.getRawContent()  %}
    <h3>{{ block.heading }}</h3>
{% endfor %}
```